# Restore a postgresql database from a .pgdump file

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pg-restore

I have a .pgdump file, which I want to use it to restore the database. I've tried `pg_restore -d dbname datadump_filename` in psql, but I got nothing. I ensured the path for `PostgreSQL Binary Path` in pgAdmin4 is the correct work directory where the dump file is.

The data dump file is binary file.

Comment: `pg_restore` is a command line tool, just like `psql` so "trying pg_restore in psql" doesn't make sense. You need to run `pg_restore` just like you ran `psql`

Comment: Don't confuse the shell with the Postgres interactive client `psql`.

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin, but I would expect that the "PostgreSQL Binary Path" needs to point to the directory where the executable of `pg_restore`  is located, not the location of the dump file.

Comment: Add `-v` as in `pg_restore -v -d dbname datadump_filename` and see if there is any output.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things I changed to make it work.

I changed the pgAdmin4 path to the pg_restore path. To get the path on Mac, I ran `which psql` in the terminal.

Then I created a new db manually in pgAdmin4 `mydb`

Lastly, ran the command in the terminal `pg_restore -x --no-owner mydb <DATA DUMP FILE>`

The `-x --no-owner` flags stops pg_restore trying to set the ownership of the objects to the original owner.

`-d` flag can be ignored if the db was created manually.

Comment: I am not seeing `pg_restore -x --no-owner mydb <DATA DUMP FILE>` working. `pg_restore` needs  to restore(or connect) to either a database(`-d`) or file(`-f`) . To have it work it would need to be `pg_restore -x --no-owner -d mydb <DATA DUMP FILE>`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I manually created `mydb` before I ran the command, so actually `-d` is redundant, and I don't think it will be executed successfully if the database already exists and you also use the `d` flag.

Comment: Read the docs [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html): "pg_restore can operate in two modes. If a database name is specified, pg_restore connects to that database and restores archive contents directly into the database. Otherwise, a script containing the SQL commands necessary to rebuild the database is created and written to a file or standard output. " And database name is specified with `-d`.

Comment: And it can execute successfully if `-d <db_name>` is specified and the database already exists, though if the database already has objects in it you probably would want to add `-c` to clean the old objects before restoring the new ones. Bottom line `pg_restore`  is a client program and needs to connect to a database to restore to a database.